# Ошибка TL в решении задачи

Tags: c++

Есть задача:

> На различных мероприятиях команда стажировок регулярно разыгрывает призы в лотерею.
>
> Организаторы выбирают 10 случайных различных чисел от 1 до 32. Каждому участнику выдается лотерейный билет, на котором записаны 6 различных чисел от 1 до 32. Билет считается выигрышным, если в нем есть не менее 3 выбранных организаторами числа.
>
> Помогите Юле, напишите программу, которая будет сообщать, какие билеты выигрышные.
>
> Формат ввода
>
> В первой строке входных данных записаны 10 различных целых чисел ai (1 ≤ ai ≤ 32) — выбранные организаторами числа.
>
> Во второй строке записано одно целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 1000) — количество лотерейных билетов, выданных на мероприятии.
>
> В каждой из n последующих строк записаны 6 различных целых чисел bj (1 ≤ bj ≤ 32) — числа, записанные на очередном лотерейном билета.
>
> Формат вывода
>
> Выведите n строк. Для каждого лотерейного билета в порядке следования во входных данных выведите строку Lucky, если билет выигрышный, иначе выведите Unlucky.

И вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int lucky [10], n, copy1, copy2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        cin >> lucky [i];
    }

    cin >> n;
    int res [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; i ++)
        {
            cin >> copy1;

            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k ++)
            {
                if (copy1 == lucky [k]) copy2 ++;
            }
        }

        if (copy2 >= 3) res [i] = 1;
        else res [i] = 0;

        copy2 = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        if (res [i] == 1) cout << "Lucky\n";
        else cout << "Unlucky\n";
    }
}
```

Пишет - превышено время исполнения, но ошибку найти так и не могу. Набирал с телефона, за формат кода прошу простить.

Comment: Вы хоть напишите, какие входные данные, ограничения и т.д. Вам лень спрашивать - с чего нам будет не лень отвечать?...

Comment: "превышено время исполнения" означает, что ваш код слишком медленный. Судя по всему, вы старались сделать его как можно короче, рьяно экономя на названиях переменных и форматировании. К сожалению, к высокой производительности таким путем не прийти.

Comment: @VTT там просто 0 реакции со стороны кода(((

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 6; i ++)` — бесконечный цикл.

Comment: А вы хоть сам этот код запускали? Вот например цикл `for (int j = 0; j < 6; i ++) {` переменная `j`, а увеличивается переменная `i` - очень показательный пример, почему никогда не следует давать переменным имена из одной буквы.

Comment: @VTT *никогда не следует давать переменным имена из одной буквы* -- прямо таки никогда-никогда?

Comment: @VTT, спасибо, зашло.

Comment: Опубликуйте теперь в виде ответа.

Comment: писать циклы и заморачиваться с массивами как то несовременно. Есть контейнеры, есть альгоритмы  в STL...

Comment: @PinkTux Да, прямо никогда. Макконел ("Совершенный Код")указывает, что оптимальная длина названия переменной 9-15 символов. Одно- дву- буквенные идентификаторы следовало бы запретить на уровне синтаксиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы вообще делал так:

```
int main ()
{
    int n;
    int lucky[33] = { 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        cin >> n;
        lucky[n] = 1;
    }
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            int m;
            cin >> m;
            sum += lucky[m];
        }
        cout << ((sum >= 3) ? "Lucky\n" : "Unlucky\n");
    }
}
```

И еще - учтите, что

```
cin >> n;
int res [n];
```

такое **стандарт** С++ не разрешает!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как-нибудь так. 
Ваш вариант не компилируется.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int numbers_in_one_ticket = 6;
const int lucky_numbers = 10;
int main() {
    int lucky[lucky_numbers], number_of_tickets = 0;
    cout << "Enter 10 lucky numbers\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < lucky_numbers; i++)
    {
        cin >> lucky[i];
    }
    cout << "\nEnter number of tickets\n";
    cin >> number_of_tickets;
    int **tickets = new int * [number_of_tickets];
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_tickets; i++)
    {
        tickets[i] = new int[numbers_in_one_ticket];
    }
    srand(NULL);
    for (int j = 0; j < number_of_tickets; j++)
    {
        int numbers_in_common = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers_in_one_ticket; i++)
        {
            tickets[j][i] = rand() % 32;
            for (int i = 0; i < lucky_numbers; i++)
            {
                if (lucky[i] == tickets[j][i])
                    numbers_in_common++;
            }
        }
        if (numbers_in_common >= 3)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers_in_one_ticket; i++)
            {
                cout << tickets[j][i] << " ";   
            }
            cout << "Lucky\n";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers_in_one_ticket; i++)
            {
                cout << tickets[j][i] << " ";
            }
                cout << "Unlucky\n";
        }
    }
    delete[] tickets;
}
```